# Specify default depth buffer precision

Tags: firefox, webgl

In Firefox (Windows OS) the default WebGL context comes with a 16-bit depth buffer, is there any way to get at least 24 bit?

Comment: Are you sure it's 16bits in firefox? how are you checking?

Comment: I am sure that on windows it is 16bit and on Mac OS X it is 24 bit, you can check it for example using www.webglreport.com here is my results: joxi.net/MAjMV3VIvbMe72

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it was a bug in Firefox, it was fixed here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1427668

In Firefox 59 all works okay now, again, 24-bit by default.

Answer (score 0):

No official one, no.

However creating your context with a stencil buffer using `stencil: true` during creation may result in it using 24+8 format...

However instead of relying on a trick that may fail to work in the future/on certain devices you may want to look into these options to mitigate depth-testing issues first:

- revise your clip planes setup
- [alter your depth value encoding](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/depth-precision-visualized)
- render to a framebuffer with a `DEPTH_STENCIL` renderbuffer or a [depth texture](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_depth_texture/) attachment
- as a last resort, do
  your own depth testing using a 32bit texture as a depth buffer

Comment: You might want to add you can just use a renderbuffer with DEPTH_STENCIL, no extension needed. IIRC it's required to work and I know of no GPU that supports that in anything other than 24:8

Comment: @gman thanks I've added it, I feel like just requesting stencil for the context should work just as well without any framebuffer setup.

Comment: There is an easy way to check Depth Bits:
depthBits: gl.getParameter(gl.DEPTH_BITS)
http://webglreport.com/webglreport.js used there

and I got 16 even when the stencil is true. All PC with windows 10 and latest firefox always return 16. On Mac OS X firefox return - 24.

a framebuffer is a performance drop, but yes, with framebuffer it is possible to choose depth bits manually.

Maybe you knew any trick how to use framebuffer without performance drop?